# How to use context.Fail() within dialogs

Tags: botframework

I'm having trouble understanding how to use the `IDialogContext` method `Fail` in Dialogs. I understand that it's supposed to send an exception to the parent dialog, but where does this happen? I think in the `ResumeAfter` method but I'm not entirely sure.

I'm asking this because I have several dialogs branching from a root dialog, and I'm trying to figure out a way to propagate exceptions all the way back to the root and back to where I originally call `Conversations.SendAsync` in my Controller. Any examples of doing this would be great.

Answer (score 6):

I found a good way to handle exceptions. It appears that `context.Fail` is if you want to explicitly end the context with an exception. If an exception is thrown elsewhere in the dialog and isn't caught, it will be propagated to the parent dialog and can be received in the `ResumeAfter` method. E.g.

```
public virtual async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)
{
    var message = await argument;
    await context.Call(new ChildDialog(), AfterMessageAsync);
}

private async Task AfterMessageAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
{
    try
    {
        var childResult = await result;
        await context.PostAsync($"ended child with: {childResult}");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await context.PostAsync($"ended child with exception: {ex.StackTrace}");
    }
}
```